# Can I connect external USB storage to Wi-Fi repeater

Tags: home-networking, usb-storage, repeater

My home network router does not support connecting external USB storage.

I must use it (it's used for phone and cables, as well), but I'd really like to have shared storage.

In general, I thought about buying a router that does support connecting external USB storage and configuring it as a repeater.

Does it make sense? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Great. So all I need to do it to buy a router that support connecting external USB storage, right?

Comment: Yes, this setup is possible and perfectly OK. I have a very similar setup at home.

Comment: Be careful when buying router. Some of them have USB port but only support USB printers, not storage devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine. It's called an Access Point when used like that. I didn't have much luck with my repeater, so I use an older router in the same manner you describe.

Although I'd suggest you may want to use the new router as the main router and use the current one as the access point (since the new one will have this feature).

@smc makes a great point in the OP comments:

> Be careful when buying router. Some of them have USB port but only support USB printers, not storage devices

Google creating access points. There are lots of video's etc and it will ensure you don't get any unexpected surprises/issues